# reprepro remove reports "not found" but reprepro list shows the package

Tags: debian, apt

I'm trying to remove a package from a local debian repo. `reprepro list` shows it, but `reprepro remove` says it's not found. The file exists in the `backup` directory but not in the `pool` directory. I guess that means it's not really there?

```
$ reprepro -b /opt/debrepo list qa
qa|beats|amd64: beats-blt 1.2.1-rc1

$ reprepro -b /opt/debrepo remove qa  beats-blt
Exporting indices...
Not removed as not found: beats-blt

$ reprepro -b /opt/debrepo remove qa  beats-blt_1.2.1-rc1
Exporting indices...
Not removed as not found: beats-blt_1.2.1-rc1
```

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem, except that the list command didn't see it either, but the include command thought it was still there when I tried to add it. This fixed it for me:

```
reprepro deleteunreferenced
```